# Finding Loot in Rivers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found armor and tools in a river. (all undamaged)

What has happened?

Is this normal for Minecraft to give loot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When armor-wearing/tool-wielding zombies drown and become drowned, it drops everything it has, at full durability.

You can use this trick to get a juicy set of armor/tools from the zombies. (especially if it's enchanted)